# RHEL 6 filesystem

Tags: filesystems, rhel, mount

I'm reading about RHEL 6 and getting confused about a knowledge check.

It tells me that not to use a computer to give an answer for this but the question is on a RHEL 6 system, 
mount /dev/sda12 /acctdata if this command executes correctly, from where on the local system can the filesystem be accessed?

Could the answer be /etc/fstab since it reads the content of the /etc/fstab configuration file to see if the given file system is listed? Hands on practice would possibly help me understand more than just reading but it tells me not to.

Comment: What do you understand about the `mount` command?

Comment: What part of "not to use a computer to give an answer" don't you understand?  You are currently cheating openly.  If you want to learn, then study the material but getting others to answer your test questions will not help anyone including you.

Comment: Cheating? Umm This isn't a test, its a self-study course from a computer and after reading and it calls it a knowledge check. I'm new to Linux as of 2 days ago. If I don't understand something I have the right to ask others who do understand and who are willing to help me understand what I am missing. If you don't want to help me understand that's fine but you don't have to be rude to me. But since you were I really hope that made you feel better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `mount /dev/sda12 /acctdata` will mount partition #12 of disk sda to `/acctdata`.

Therefore, the answer is "the filesystem can be accessed on `/acctdata`".

> Could the answer be /etc/fstab since it reads the content of the /etc/fstab configuration file to see if the given file system is listed?

No, `/etc/fstab` is used to list partitions that must be automatically mounted at boot -- or to provide default mount options for them.